# Qual o plural para ar condicionado?

Tags: número-gramatical

Com a nova regra do acordo ortográfico algumas palavras perderam o hífen (`-`), não sei se é o caso de `ar-condicionado`. Não sei se a palavra passa a ser:

- ar condicionado;
- ou arcondicionado;
- ou se se mantém como ar-condicionado.

Meu corretor ortográfico acusa como sendo *ar-condicionado* a versão correta, mas muitas palavras antes do acordo ainda são aceitas.

Todavia pesquisei e não encontrei, alguns dizem que o plural correto é ares condicionados (soa estranho) e outros dizem que é ar-condicionados (o que não sei se é valido na nova regra do acordo).

Qual seria a maneira correta, tanto no plural quanto no singular?

Answer (score 13):

No Brasil, antes do Acordo Ortográfico, ***ar condicionado*** era ar, e ***ar-condicionado*** era o aparelho. Os plurais eram ***ares condicionados*** para o ar (nada de especial aqui; simplesmente pluralizas o substantivo e o adjetivo) e ***ares-condicionados*** para o aparelho.

Depois do Acordo Ortográfico, temos um problema. ***Ar-condicionado*** não consta do [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da Língua Portuguesa (VOC)](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?sel=contain&action=simplesearch&base=form&query=ar-condicionado), que deve integrar os vocabulários ortográficos de todos os países de língua portuguesa de acordo com a nova grafia. Isto sugere que mesmo o aparelho passou a ser *ar condicionado*. Por outro lado *ar-condicionado* e *ares-condicionados*  aparecem ainda no [*Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa* (VOLP) da Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario), que diz reger-se pelo Acordo Ortográfico (mandei-lhes um mail pedir esclarecimentos). Já o [*Portal da Língua Portuguesa* baseado em Portugal](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?sel=exact&action=simplesearch&base=form&sel=exact&query=ar-condicionado&ok=OK) não inclui *ar-condicionado*. Podemos é excluir com segurança a possibilidade *arcondicionado*. Esta forma não aparece nem no VOLP nem no VOC, e não faz sentido à luz do Acordo [(Base XV, observação ao ponto 1 ― palavras compostas com hífen):](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990)

> Obs.: Certos compostos, em relação aos quais se perdeu, em certa medida, a noção de composição, grafam-se aglutinadamente: girassol, madressilva, mandachuva, pontapé, paraquedas, paraquedista, etc.

Ora nós temos clara noção que o nome é composto de duas palavras, *ar* e *condicionado*, logo a aglutinação não faria qualquer sentido.

Entretanto a divergência observa-se também entre dicionários brasileiros e portugueses. No Aulete vem [*ar-condicionado*](http://www.aulete.com.br/ar-condicionado) para o aparelho e  [*ar condicionado*](http://www.aulete.com.br/ar) para ar. O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=ar) tem apenas *ar condicionado*, e só para ar. O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ar%20condicionado) indica para o aparelho *ar-condicionado* como brasileirismo, e *ar condicionado* sem qualquer restrição. A questão é que não vejo qualquer razão para haver uma grafia no Brasil e outra em Portugal. *Facto-fato, recepção-receção* compreendem-se porque correspondem a pronúncias diferentes em Portugal e Brasil, mas na questão do hífen isso não acontece. Esperemos pela resposta da ABL.

O plural *ares condicionados* também me soa estranho, mas é o que é, com ou sem hífen. É claro que, como tudo, é uma questão de hábito, e em contexto nem soa assim tão mal: vê [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ddkeAQAAIAAJ&q=%22ares%20condicionados%22&dq=%22ares%20condicionados%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmz-X6qLLMAhXKORQKHUaCCek4PBDoAQhiMAg) e [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=x5vuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ares%20condicionados%22&dq=%22ares%20condicionados%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil74DVp7LMAhUBGxQKHfpfC5YQ6AEISTAD). Mas podes sempre dizer *aparelhos de ar condicionado*. É o que faz a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condicionamento_de_ar), que observa apenas à laia de nota que “*ar condicionado*” (sem hífen) é usado por extensão para referir o aparelho.

Comment: Não me parece que isso esteja atualizado para o acordo. Em http://voc.cplp.org/ já não aparece _ar-condicionado_, que de facto parece impossível à luz dos termos do acordo.

Comment: @Artefacto Lá aparece «conforme descrito no Acordo Ortográfico», e tem *delinquente* e *linguístico* sem trema.

Comment: Talvez não esteja atualizado? Em todo o caso, a wikipedia cita um artigo do DN ao dizer «Nenhum desses vocabulários ortográficos (da Academia Brasileira de Letras, da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, do ILTEC português, etc.) tem, porém, caráter oficial. O Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, que já tem força de lei em Portugal e no Brasil, determina a publicação de um Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum, que será o vocabulário oficial da língua portuguesa, válido para todos os países que têm o português como língua oficial, tão logo seja concluído.»

Comment: Ah e quanto à regra, estava a confundir com a regra dos prefixos. O acordo parece ter regras para usar hífen vs aglutinar, mas não para usar hífen vs. não usar.

Comment: @Artefacto Tive a ler o acordo: «Emprega-se o hífen nas palavras compostas por justaposição que não contêm formas de ligação e cujos elementos, de natureza nominal, adjetival, numeral ou verbal, constituem uma unidade sintagmática e semântica e mantêm acento próprio» [fonte](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990). Ora, parece-me que temos que distinguir o aparelho, em que *ar(-)condicionado* forma uma unidade semântica (o aparelho não é nenhum tipo de ar), do próprio ar que foi condicionado.

Comment: Talvez, mas parece-me que estás a provar mais do que querias. Se _ar condicionado_ calha aí, então devia escrever-se também dessa forma em Portugal. O que me parece mais provável é que o texto é ambíguo, e portanto a gente deve ir ao instrumento determinado pelo acordo ver (o vocabulário comum).

Comment: @Artefacto O VOC também não tem *ar condicionado*, mas tem locuções sem hífen, como *cor de vinho, fim de semana*, etc. Portanto parece-me que neste caso temos que nos amanhar sem o VOC.

Comment: As locuções são um caso diferente e plenamente previsto no Acordo (como sem hífen). E é curioso que só Portugal achou importante pô-las no vocabulário. Se não encontrasses dadas palavras inequivocamente escritas sem hífen, então poderias ter um argumento

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39036/discussion-between-jacinto-and-artefacto).

Comment: @ Artefacto O VOC não tem *pera-rocha*, que leva hífen ao abrigo da Base XV - 3. Têm no entanto *couve-lombarda* e *abóbora-menina*.

Comment: _pera-rocha_ tb não aparece nos dicionários que consultei (infopedia, priberam, michaelis, aulete). E tb nao está no vocabulário da academia brasileira, cujo link tens na resposta

Comment: @Artefacto Mas vem no Houaiss.

Comment: Acredito, estou simplesmente a dizer que não deves ler muita coisa na ausência da palavra.

Comment: @Artefacto o VOC também não tem *ótica* nem *ótico*. Tem *optico/a* mas está um confusão: põe entre parênteses (Brasil), mas indica frequência alta no corpus português.

Answer (score 5):

Em toda a minha vida - e lá se vão várias décadas - nunca me deparei com uma situação onde precisasse usar o substantivo "ar-condicionado" no plural. E também nunca ouvi.  Embora as respostas acima citem "ares-condicionados" como o plural, **não consigo imaginar uma situação onde essa palavra seja usada e soe natural**.  Quando estamos em um revendedor e vemos vários aparelhos, referimo-nos a eles como **"aqueles aparelhos de ar-condicionado"**. Tão simples!  Durante os dias incrivelmente quentes que tivemos no verão passado eu comentei várias vezes que "lá em casa o ar condicionado está ligado o tempo todo. E são quatro aparelhos".  Ninguém por estas bandas diria "aqueles ares-condicionados", "os ares-condicionados da minha casa", ou "temos dois ares-condicionados na minha sala". Quando queremos nos referir a um ambiente refrigerado dizemos: "o ar condicionado aqui está muito bom" e, havendo mais de um ambiente "o ar-condicionado daqui e o do terceiro andar estão muito bons" ou "a refrigeração está muito boa".

Comment: Fizeste-me pensar agora, se levares à letra, vais perceber que não tem grande lógica *ares condicionados*.

Comment: Não consegues imaginar? Por telefone: `Ah, e já vieram instalar os 5 ares-condicionados novos que comprámos para o *hall* de entrada?` No Brasil diriam «os 5 aparelhos de ar-condicionado»? Em Portugal, acho que não, que se usaria a versão mais curta. (Sendo que «aparelhos» não seria usado, por ser ambíguo.)

Comment: Não é ambíguo. A máquina de gelar o ar é um aparelho de ar-condicionado. Fala-se apenas ar-condicionado pois é subentendido.

Answer (score 3):

Pelos dicionários Aulete e Priberam, ar-condicionado e o plural ares-condicionados no Brasil. Creio que em Portugal seria ar condicionado e ares condicionados.

**No Aulete:**

> ar-condicionado
>   (ar-con.di.ci:o.na.do)
>   sm.
>   1. Tec. Aparelho que se destina a regular a temperatura e a umidade de ambientes fechados.
>   [Pl.: **ares-condicionados**.]
>   Fonte:http://www.aulete.com.br/ar-condicionado. Acesso em: 28 abr. 2016.

Já no dicionário Priberam encontrei duas formas: ar condicionado e ar-condicionado.

> **ar condicionado**
>   Aparelho ou sistema que regula o aquecimento ou a refrigeração de um ambiente.
>   **ar·-con·di·ci·o·na·do**
>  
>   substantivo masculino
>   [Brasil]  O mesmo que ar condicionado.
>   Plural: ares-condicionados.
>   Fonte:https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/ar-condicionado. Acesso em: 28 abr. 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Em Portugal não há lugar a usar o plural pelo que «ar condicionado» não refere ao aparelho mas sim à qualidade do ar: aquele ar cuja temperatura é controlada através de aparelho próprio chamado «aparelho de ar condicionado» ou «condicionador de ar».

Fonte: Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa Contemporânea (Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, Editorial Verbo, 2001), I Volume, página 318 «ar».

Diz-se «ar condicionado» para referir ao aparelho quando não existe ambiguidade («ligar o [aparelho de] ar condicionado»), mas a omissão não poderia ser feita no plural porque faria incidir o número numa substância (o ar) não contável.

Se uma forma sintética for mais conveniente que «aparelhos de ar condicionado», pode-se usar «climatizadores».

Comment: landric, bem-vindo ao site. Os dicionários são melhores a mostrar o que existe do que aquilo que não existe. O dicionário da Academia não define *ar condicionado* como aparelho (mas usa o conceito no exemplo, "instalação de ar condicionado", é o aparelho, não instalas ar), mas o da [Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ar-condicionado) e o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ar%20condicionado) definem; nenhum deles diz que não existe plural, e encontras o plural em uso, referindo-se ao aparelho.